# What site is there for sharing Linux custom configuration files?

Tags: linux, file-sharing, vimrc, bashrc

I remember someone here at SU gave a link to a site where you could share your **Linux custom configuration files** (like `bashrc`, `vimrc` and others), but I don't remember what was that site. I already searched it on here and on Google, but I had no luck so far...

Can you help me find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dotfiles.org/

especially (based on how you tagged the question):

- http://dotfiles.org/.bashrc
- http://dotfiles.org/.vimrc

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer, but I need 15 rep